# Visual Studio 2013 crashes on SQL Select Source/Target in SQL Schema Compare after Windows 10 upgrade

Tags: visual-studio, windows-10, schema-compare

With an existing schema compare file, or a newly created one.

Tried to change source or target via:

Menu: "SQL"
Choice: "Select Source..." OR "Select Target..."

Visual Studio 2013 then crashed with message:
"Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 has stopped working ..."

Answer (score 0):

Thank you once again Stack Overflow for the solution, which was suggested by a similar problem here:

[Why does select source for a SQL Schema Comparison cause VS2012 to crash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15644728/why-does-select-source-for-a-sql-schema-comparison-cause-vs2012-to-crash)

I could not up-vote this solution as I still have insufficient reputation.

Solution was to open RedEdit (Command-Run RegEdit)
Navigate to:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\SSDT\ConnectionMruList

Delete all entries other than Default (won't let you delete that)

Restarted Visual Studio 2013 and it works again.